# Laravel Nova select field default value

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

How can i set a default value in Laravel Nova in a select field?

```
   Select::make('Car')->options([
        'mercedes' => 'Mercedes',
        'audi' => 'Audi',
        'bmw' => 'BMW',
    ]),
```

[image]

https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/fields.html#select-field

In this example i want that `mercedes` is the default value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`default`](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/fields.html#default-values) function

```
Select::make('Car')->options([
    'mercedes' => 'Mercedes',
    'audi' => 'Audi',
    'bmw' => 'BMW',
])->default('bmw'),
```

Answer (score 8):

I found out in case someone has the same problem.

```
 Select::make('Car')
    ->options([
        'mercedes' => 'Mercedes',
        'audi' => 'Audi',
        'bmw' => 'BMW',
    ])
    ->withMeta(['value' => 'mercedes']),
```

Comment: But this may override the saved data from the database.

Comment: This does override saved data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using enum on your database

```
Select::make('Car')->options([
    'mercedes' => 'Mercedes',
    'audi' => 'Audi',
    'bmw' => 'BMW',
])->default(0),
```